# WebStorm поддержка NodeJs and NPM.

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webstorm

Нашел на просторах следующий код и попытался его реализовать в WebStorm.

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest (requare , response) {
console.log(request.uri);

response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type" : "text/plain"});
response write("Hello World!");
response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is renned");
```

Однако IDE знать не знает о`(requare , response)` При нажатие **alt + enter** импорта не предлагает. NodeJs и NPM установлены, в path так же добавлены.

При подключении **node.exe** npm, как видно на скрине, таки отображается. В общем, как заставить это работать?

[image: Так я пытаюсь подключить подключить модуль]

Comment: а что, по-вашему, ту нужно импортировать по alt + enter? и что IDE должна знать о параметрах объявленной вами функции? Почему она должна знать что-то особенное о `(requare , response)`?

Comment: Это разве не стандартные команды в js?

Comment: Пример был взят отсюда - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPrqoGVC4Rw

Comment: нет, это не стандартные команды, это имена параметров вашей функции. вы с тем же успехом могли бы назвать их foo и bar. кстати, я полагаю, вы на самом деле хотели написать `function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log(request.url);`? непонятно, откуда взялся `console.log(request.uri)`, если имя параметра - `require`? Да и `uri` на самом деле`url`

Comment: Ладно, поспешил я, наверное, с опросами. Нужно было пару дней поизучать матчасть. Но все же, в примере из видео все это было принято, синтаксис подсвечен, все как положено. У меня же подчеркнуто как ошибка. И как узнать что npm подключен?

Comment: а что вы имеете в виду под подключением npm? суда по скриншотам, у вас правильно установлен и выбран интерпретатор, IDE видит глобально установленные node_modules, подключена node.js core библиотека... Что не так?

Comment: Код из примера (ссылка выше) у меня не запустился. И (requare , response) подчеркнуты как ошибка. Хотя код точно как в примере. Это и смутило

Comment: код ваш прекрасно запускается (только  `console.log(request.uri)` возвращает undefined, т.к. не определены ни request, ни uri). да и подчеркивание единственное для (requare , response) - от spell checker

Answer (score 1):

Более корректный (работающий) пример кода:

```
var http = require('http');

function onRequest(request, response) {
    console.log(request.url);

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World!");
    response.end();
}


http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("Server is renned");
```

в любом случае, тип параметра не указан явно нигде; IDE пытается ресолвить методы httpserverrequest и httpserverresponce просто по имени